# How to mock CallableStatement in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock `CallablaStatement` in order to achieve 100% code coverage. 
I am using Mockito.
I am getting `NullPointerException` on `statement.setLong(1, 928343);` or while setting any `statement.set` method.

Please help.

**code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/execute/{param1}/{param2}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void performAction(@PathVariable long param1, @PathVariable long param2) {

    String sp = "{call user.performAction(?,?,?)}}";

    Connection conn;
    CallableStatement statement;

    try {
        conn = customConnectionPool.getConnection();
        if (conn != null) {
            statement = conn.prepareCall(sp);
            statement.setLong(1, 928343);
            statement.setString(2, "234342");
            statement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

            statement.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.error("exception");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception exep) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Junit test:**

```
@Test
public void performActionTest() {
    when(customConn.getConnection()).thenReturn(conn);
    mockMvc.perform(post("/execute/" + 345678 + "/" +"345678"));

}
```

Comment: Your test code is missing here. How are you currently doing it?

Comment: @ernest_k - added unit test code snippet.

Comment: you also need to mock `conn.prepareCall(sp);` to return a mock callablestatement. typically that would look like `when(conn.prepareCall("{call user.performAction(?,?,?)}}")).thenReturn(mock(CallableStatement.class));`

Comment: @njzk2 - okay, I can do that, but I am not getting the exception on that line. I am getting the exception on the  " statement.setLong(1, 928343);"

Comment: @njzk2 - Thanks man, that worked like a charm. How can I cover catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.error("exception");
    } part?

Comment: *I am trying to mock CallablaStatement in order to achieve 100% code coverage*: please, don't do that. Code coverage means nothing if the tests just execute code without actually testing anything. If your test passes (and it will with your strategy) even though your query is plain wrong, then your test is meaningless. Write an actual test that actually executes the query and verifies that it does what it's supposed to do. And learn to use the try-with-resources statement.

Comment: Yup, I agree with you, but 100% code coverage is mandatory. :(

Comment: @amseager I'm not advocating for not testing the code. I'm advocating to test it with a test that does something useful, i.e. actually verifies that the code works as expected.

Comment: as long as you verify that when you get to the  `executeUpdate` your statement has the right parameters, your test is meaningful

Comment: regarding the exception: you should not swallow it. You should probably catch more specific exceptions and either translate them to something that's useful for your users, and if needed have a catch-all that translates into a 500 error. (although the translation might happen in a controlleradvice). Either way, your test should end up with testing that the status is definitely not `status().isOk()`

Comment: 100% coverage is pointless, it means you've wasted time writing tests for things like pojo get/set methods... In the case of "CallableStatement", a unit test is not what you want, you're not going to be test anything. Write yourself some nice integration tests which connect to a test db instance and actually test the logic... The value of an integration test in this type of circumstance in orders of magnitude more useful than something where you've mocked-out all of jdbc. Dao layer tests need to be performed against a DB, in-mem DB for simple cases or integration test DB instances for others.